# AdbCommandRejectedException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

## I'm trying to run a project in Android Studio and I keep getting this weird error.

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 3004a4ebc1303100: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 3004a4ebc1303100: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked in DDMS perspective that your device is showing online?
   Try Resetting adb from the DDMS

Comment: When I reset the adb I got this error "[2015-06-25 11:53:18 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2015-06-25 11:53:18 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1"

Comment: yeah. try reconnecting Device , Data cables etc.
I commonly get that error too. But it goes away after reconnecting. or ur data cable is faulty replace that.
    And I am assuming that U hv debug mode on in your device settings.